# Why this time I can not selec one column from a DataFrame by print(['column1'])?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I can selected one `column` from a `DataFrame`, for example: the code like `print(df['201809'])` works:

```
df = pd.read_csv('xxxx.csv', low_memory=False)

print(df.info()]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 11 entries, 0 to 10
Data columns (total 4 columns):
BO_product2    11 non-null object
201808         11 non-null float64
201809         11 non-null float64
4              11 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 440.0+ bytes 

print(df['201809'])      # works fine
    None
0     1.634931e+06
1     2.653640e+08
2     7.475315e+07
3     9.710830e+06
4     3.023899e+08
5     1.087862e+08
6     2.031106e+08
7     3.556234e+08
8     5.830665e+06
9     8.766841e+08
10    7.544689e+07
Name: 201809, dtype: float64
```

However `print(df['4'])` don't. Any tips or ideas is here?

> *PS: if i save the `df.to_csv('yy.csv)` to local file in `csv` format, `print(a['4'])`works after `df = pd.read_csv('yy.csv').*

```py
print(df['4'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3063, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '4'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/2.py", line 45, in <module>
    he()
  File "E:/Python/2.py", line 26, in he
    print(a['4'])
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2685, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2692, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2486, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3065, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute the below:

```
[type(i) for i in df.columns]
#[str, str, str, int]
```

For columns having type `int` you should call the column as `df[4]` and not `df['4']`

Probably the reason why it is getting written as string is due to the `quoting` builtin function. From the docs:

> > quoting : optional constant from csv module
> >
> > defaults to csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL. If you have set a float_format then floats are >>converted to strings and thus csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC will treat them as non->>numeric

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great. Thx a lot! ^.^